# Recorrer un arreglo para calcular el promedio y obtener el promedio más alto.

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un ejercicio donde voy a imprimir un arreglo de materias y el promedio sacado por materia, pero necesito saber cual es el mayor promedio sacado.

Este es el script:

```
var porcentaje = (cantidadRespuestaSi / cantidadPreguntas) * 100;

                    var parcialMaterias = {};

                    parcialMaterias.idCarrera = idCodigo;
                    parcialMaterias.nombre =  nombre[x];
                    parcialMaterias.porcentaje = porcentaje.toFixed(2);

                    //parcialMaterias.cantidadPreguntas = cantidadPreguntas;
                    if (!isNaN(porcentaje)) {
                        globalMaterias.push(parcialMaterias);
                    }


                })
```

Estaré sumamente agradecido con quien me pueda ayudar !... Muchas gracias =D

Comment: En lugar de poner una foto, copia y pega el codigo editando tu pregunta

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia alan

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El mayor promedio de que?

Comment: El mayor porcentaje sacado por materia dentro de un arreglo @gbianchi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creas una variable inicializada a 0 antes de empezar, y vas actualizando cuándo calculas para cada material si el valor del material es mayor.

```
var pmayor = 0;

....

if (porcentaje > pmayor) { pmayor = porcentaje; }
```

Comment: Ok Carmen Gracias

Comment: Para eso estamos :)